# Difference in "Adequate" and "Enough/sufficient"

Tags: differences

I heard that "Adequate" and "Enough/sufficient" are almost similar words. But still there is a difference in the use of them. The question I would like to ask is the following:

> Can on give example of two "sentences" containing the word "adequate", which can not be replaced by "enough/sufficient"? Similarly, "enough" can not be replaced by "adequate"?

Comment: There is a difference in tone.  Especially when spoken, "adequate" implies "barely meets specifications", whereas "sufficient" suggests that the specifications have been comfortably (if not generously) met.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three can be used to mean more or less the same thing, but my ancient Australian Concise Oxford Dictionary 1989 describes "adequate" as:

> proportionate (*to* the requirements); sufficient, satisfactory;
>   barely sufficient.

So in the last-mentioned usage there's a sense that "adequate" is not quite as complete as "sufficient" or "enough". However, I'm struggling to think of a sentence to give as an example. Perhaps:

> "He gave what could at very best be described as an adequate answer."

"Enough" can sometimes (depending on context) mean that the action is complete or the limit has been reached, whereas "adequate" and "sufficient" would not usually suggest fullness but rather the right amount to meet the need. Examples of this usage would be:

> "I've had enough of his rude behaviour!" [meaning I'm tired of it]
>
> "Enough said." [meaning I should say no more]

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: maybe it's a lexicon of discretionary spelling?